# Not able to load SXA Site after configuring its domain

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client

We have many SXA Sites and we are trying to launch a new site with our domain https://domainA.info. We updated Host Name and Target Host Name fields on site definition item and published as well. The site is there in SXA Site manager without any conflicts but the site is not loading. We are getting the message 'The site can't be reached'. However, if we configure the same site another domain 'https://domainB.info' (a test domain), it is working fine. But, this test domain is used many times in other SXA Sites for testing. If we do not map this test domain to any of our sites, we are getting below screenshot which is not the case for our actual domain. Is that something wrong at the networking end or configuration from Sitecore end?

**Domain**: https://domainB.info  - working

[image: Domain: https://domainB.info]

**Domain**: https://domainA.info  - not working

[image]

Comment: What does the logs state? Did you configure the site binding in IIS? It could be the domain name is too long. I think the logs will help you solve this issue.

Comment: We got the domain from network team. Just want to ensure that everything is good from Sitecore end

Comment: So does the logs contain any errors/informational messages?

Comment: @ManideepYechuri Did you find the solution for your problem? If yes then please mentioned as answer so that others cab be benefited with the solution.

Comment: Also having a similar issue on Azure PAAS environment.